# Resultado incrementação?

Tags: c, c++, operadores

Tenho uma duvida quanto a esta expressão:

```
y-=++x
```

Consigo dividir esta expressão em duas?

```
x= x+1
```

e depois?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei se isso que você procura, pelo que deu para entender, você que dividir em duas equações.

Como você já mostrou uma que é

```
x = x+1;
```

embaixo dessa equação basta colocar essa que vai funcionar normalmente

`y-=x;` ou `y = y- x;`

Answer (score 2):

De fato, embora funcione, fica pouco legível desta forma e pode induzir a erro na interpretação. Ficaria melhor assim:

```
x++;
y -= x;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Increment.c).